# Scala: constructor with two paretneheses

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala.
What does following syntax mean?

```
case class User(val id: Long)(val username: String)
```

I've read about currying in scala, but explain please how it related to construction above (if related).
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just like partially-applied functions, a constructor (which is a function from its arguments to the constructed type) can be partially applied, in this case:

```
scala> case class User(val id: Long)(val username: String)
defined class User

scala> val userBuilder = User(123L) _
userBuilder: String => User = <function1>
```

Note the type of the resulting `userBuilder` - it's a *function* from `String` (the remaining parameter) to `User`

Now, like partially applied functions, you can apply  this result to a String and get a `User` instance:

```
scala> val user = userBuilder("a")
user: User = User(123)

scala> user.username
res1: String = a
```

**When is this useful?**

1. When you want to construct many instances with common values for a subset of the arguments, e.g.:

   ```
   case class Person(lastName: String)(val firstName: String)

   class Family(lastName: String, firstNames: List[String]) {
     def getMembers: List[Person] = {
       val creator = Person(lastName) _ // will be reused for each first name!
       firstNames.map(creator)
     }
   }
   ```
2. When you want to use one argument as the default value of another one:

   ```
   case class Measure(min: Int)(val max: Int = min*2)

   Measure(5)()   // max = 10
   Measure(5)(12) // default overridden, max = 12
   ```
3. When you want to use `implicit` arguments, which *must reside in a separate, last argument list of the function*, as described int the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (Chapter 7.2):

> A method or constructor can have only one implicit
>   parameter list, and it must be the last parameter list given.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to construct the object in steps.

```
val user = User(123L) _ // user now has only the ID

// later on
val completeUser = user("moreo") // user now also has the username
```

This is generally useful when you want to have your object follow an interface, but need to pass additional parameters, so you first initialise your object with those parameters and then later you get a function that can follow the interface.

Comment: not accurate - your answer doesn't compile, you should write `User(123L) _ ` to get the partially-applied constructor.

Comment: Also, important to note, that the type of `user` here is _not_ `User`, but a function: `String => User`

Comment: Thanks you for answer. I've tried to do following: case class User(val id: Long, implicit val repository: UserRepository), but it has compile error, so when I've changed to the  case class User(val id: Long)(implicit val repository: UserRepository) - it woks. But why first approach does not work. repository property is required for class, and as you told, if I can initialise User class without second param, than class would be inconsistent. How to solve this issue?

Comment: @moreo, if you change to implicit, you have to provide the value in the context and it gets applied during the first call immediately, not in two steps as shown in my answer. It is a valid, but different use case.